# Vbs SendKeys to 1 line

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

How can I get this to work with only one SendKeys line?

```
If IsNumeric(nTo) Then
    wscript.sleep 1000
    Do Until nTo = -1
    a.SendKeys (number, " ")
    number = number + 1
    nTo = nTo - 1
    Loop
End If
```

I'm getting error on SendKeys row.

Comment: (A) The error is because the SendKeys syntax you're using is wrong. It takes one argument, the string to send. (B) Your loop will run nto + 1 times, is that what you want. (C) Do you want the numbers to be sent to the other application or the spaces or both? (D) If you describe what you're trying to do in the larger script (of which this is a snippet,) we might be able to suggest a more robust method than SendKeys

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the target of your `SendKeys` I can't test it, but something like this should work:

```
s = ""
Do Until nTo = -1
    s = s & number & " "
    number = number + 1
    nTo = nTo - 1
Loop
a.SendKeys s
```